# Websocket with Django Channels and IIS - No route found for path

Tags: python, django, iis, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to deploy my Django application to my IIS server, but my websocket doesn't work when accessing via IIS, only locally. What did I miss?

When I access via IIS:

```
new WebSocket('ws://server:8000/ws/notificacoes') -> error 1006 
Log: ValueError: No route found for path 'ws/notificacoes'
```

When I access via python runserver:

```
new WebSocket('ws://http://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/notificacoes') -> connected
Log: WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/notificacoes [127.0.0.1:53541]
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/notificacoes [127.0.0.1:53541]
```

consumers.py

```
class NotificacaoConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = 'notificacoes'

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def notificacao_update(self, event):
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': 'Notificação atualizada!'
        }))
```

routing.py

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('ws/notificacoes', NotificacaoConsumer.as_asgi(), name='notificacao'),
]
```

asgi.py

```
from index.routing import websocket_urlpatterns
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "web.settings")
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns))
        ),
    }
)
```

Edit: Here is my web.config file configured with reverse proxy. Django Channels is running Daphne on port 8002

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" />
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="" />
        <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="web.settings" />
        <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="logs\wfastcgi.log" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="Django Handler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python\python.exe|C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    </handlers>
        <modules>
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions statusCodes="500" verbosity="Warning" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <!-- Reverse proxy for Daphne running on 8002 -->
                <rule name="WebSocket Proxy" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="ws*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_CONNECT}" pattern="*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8002/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_EXTENSIONS" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#flask-with-socketio There are known issues to host Python WebSocket implementation on IIS.

Comment: @LexLi I appreciate your response but I couldn't identify anything valid. I think it's something related to reverse proxy, as IIS doesn't identify the path, or am I wrong?

Comment: There are a few things you might consider explicitly: 1) wfastcgi isn't the right way to go. If you switch to HttpPlatformHandler, you don't need those reverse proxy rules either. 2) Python WebSocket implementation doesn't work well with IIS unless you disable compression.

Comment: @LexLi I disabled compression, restarted all services (daphne, redis, etc) and now it's working as it should...I was about to give up. Thanks for help =)

Comment: Then clearly you can post and accept your own answer below, so that future readers can learn from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Lex Li, I disabled compression, restarted all related services and it worked as it should.